# how does Autosys virtual machine work

Tags: virtual-machine, autosys, jil

I first heard the notion of autosys virtual machines, which seems capable of  offloading a heavy loaded autosys job.

From some jil file examples I was able to make some oberversations:

- in the jil file for a job, if there is a type attribute, does a
  "type: v" mean virtual machine? But I also noticed in some other VM
  jil example there is no "type" attribute, and the machine name is
  like an alias with a "_V" suffix.
- Do we need to specify two physical servers in the jil with one of them serving a primary
  and the  other backup (virtual) one?
- what do attributes factor and max_load mean, and how are they properly setup?
- How can we verify that both servers are hit if the jil file were configured as such? I supposed they are in log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify 2 machines for virtual. you can have 1 and use it as a new name or more recognizable one. If you specify 2 or more behind your set virtual machine, job will only run on one machine and not all. Depending on what virtual machine you define is how the scheduler will pick on which it should execute. With the new AE SP7 there are new possibilities like round robin and other options. I would suggest reading up on those and decide what best fits your need.